# php 5.4 upload progress with custom session handling

Tags: php, file-upload

With my organizations PHP app, we setup custom PHP session storage in our database, since we have multiple web servers that didn't share the default serialized files well. Also in PHP 5.3 we implemented progress bars for file uploads on our dev environments. We utilized a DLL provided here (http://downloads.php.net/pierre/). Now we have updated to php 5.4 and while we know that it has built-in support for getting information about files as they are being uploaded, the super-global variable for the session appears to not have any data for us. We either need to know how to:

1. Use our custom session-storing methods when PHP stores the information about the file being uploaded.
2. Get a compiled version of the upload progress dll for php 5.4

Comment: AFAIK the PHP manual should cover case 1. you ask for. Did you run into any specific problems following it or were you not able to locate the documentation? This feedback might come a little late, if you found a solution in the meantime your own, please leave an answer.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, but I have found nothing for #1. I ended up compiling a version for php 5.4 using the pecl source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update on this: towards the end of 2013, we switched to using the [XHR progress events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress) so we no longer depend on any PHP modules for the progress (and we are currently up to PHP 5.6, considering moving up to PHP 7 soon).